# JQ Can't Parse JSON Containing Whitespace

Tags: bash, jq

In a Bash script I'm trying to parse a parameterized json string assigned to a variable.

*(I'm providing a trivialized version here of a much larger script to demostrate the issue.)*

Both examples are valid json, why does only one work ?

Given:

```
VALUE="1234"
```

The following produces the expected output

```
GOOD_JSON='{"key":$VALUE}';
echo $(jq -n --arg VALUE "$VALUE" $GOOD_JSON)
##Output:
#{ "key": "1234" }
```

However introducing a single whitespace character causes an error

```
BAD_JSON='{"key": $VALUE}';
echo $(jq -n --arg VALUE "$VALUE" $BAD_JSON)
##Output:
#jq: error: syntax error, unexpected end of file (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
#{"key":
#jq: 1 compile error
```

This is on MacOS using Bash and Zsh, with versions. 1.5 and 1.7.1 of JQ.

Comment: Your shell syntax is wrong. It needs to be `"$GOOD_JSON"` and `"$BAD_JSON"` **with the quotes**. This is a class of bug that https://shellcheck.net/ will point out automatically.

Comment: (`echo $(anything)` is also wrong -- it should be `echo "$(anything)"` or, better, just `anything`; no reason for the command substitution or the `echo` at all; see also [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)).

Comment: (also, albeit _mostly_ more as a convention matter than a correctness matter, use lowercase names for your own variables; in POSIX-compliant shells (which zsh isn't) you can safely write `for path in */` without breaking things, very much unlike `for PATH in */`; this is advised by POSIX in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html -- that standard speaks explicitly to environment variables, but setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable so the convention necessarily applies there too).

Comment: (...that said, one of the many ways in which zsh defies the POSIX standard is that it _does_ have special names outside the reserved all-caps namespace, so `for path in` _can and does_ break things there).

Comment: (btw, notice how jq's error message suggested "Unix shell quoting issues"? It wasn't wrong about that).

Comment: Ahhhh that's it! @CharlesDuffy, if you drop all this in to an answer I'll go ahead and accept it. Thanks!